# SMTP Connect with Socket and SSL

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, ssl, smtp

i'm trying to create a simple client of SMTP with socket in C#, heres what i have:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Socket socket;
            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            // connect to the SMTP server
            socket.Connect(new IPEndPoint(Dns.GetHostEntry("smtp.gmail.com").AddressList[0], int.Parse("587")));
            PrintRecv(socket);
            SendCommand(socket, string.Format("HELO {0}\r\n", Dns.GetHostName()));
            SendCommand(socket, "STARTTLS\r\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Done");

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void SendCommand(Socket socket, string com)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(">>>" + com);
        socket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(com));
        PrintRecv(socket);
    }
    static void PrintRecv(Socket socket)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[500];
        socket.Receive(buffer);
        Console.WriteLine("<<<" + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
    }
```

As you see i'm using GMAIL, and it needs to use SSL...My problem is when i try using SSLStream like this:

```
Stream s = GenerateStreamFromString("quit\r\n");
            SslStream ssl = new SslStream(s); //All OK until here
            ssl.AuthenticateAsClient(System.Environment.MachineName);// <<< MY PROBLEM
```

I think i don't fully understand this SslStream, i searched a lot(saw those examples on MSDN)...
In simple words, i need to know how to setup this **SslStream** to be used on the SMTP.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't leveraging the built-in classes for this?

Comment: The main reason of me doing this with sockets is to fully understand how SMTP works

Comment: You can do that without _also_ learning how SSL works. Better to focus on the goal then all of the possibilities.

Comment: its just because i started with gmail, and it doesnt have a non-SSL SMTP

Comment: Sticking to the goals, another email service would likely make it easier to learn. But if that isn't what you're after, the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt) will likely be most helpful.

Comment: `SslStream` should usually wrap a `NetworkStream`. Did you look at the example on MSDN? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified the server that you share the SslStream with when you are trying to authenticate. You left it as your machine name instead.

The solution would look something like this

```cs
SslStream secureStream = new SslStream(new NetworkStream(ClientSocket));
secureStream.AuthenticateAsClient("smtp.gmail.com");
```

If it worked correctly you should be able to send resend HELO using the stream and receive an output along the lines of:
`250-smtp.gmail.com at your service`